# Read li elements from web page and store it in array in OpenTest to check for duplicate items

Tags: automated-tests, opentest

3 `li` items all are different.
If all `li` are the same it means duplicate and we have to automate this scenario

I expect that code should able to automate the process of finding duplicate li items

```js
$runAction("org.getopentest.selenium.ReadElementText", {
  locator: $data("locators/Profile").ClientsCSP,
  $localData: {
    description: "$output.text"
  }
});
var str1 = $localData.abc;
$log(str1);
```

```html
<div data-autoid="Clients" class="m-section ItemList__itemList___2dOxf m-body" style="" xpath="1">
  <ul>
    <li data-autoid="Clients_item_0" class="ItemList__label___1N5Nz">1-800 Contacts</li>
    <li data-autoid="Clients_item_1" class="ItemList__label___1N5Nz">10 Advertising</li>
    <li data-autoid="Clients_item_2" class="ItemList__label___1N5Nz">clients_23rd July</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

store `li` items in the array and if duplicate found log it

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go about it is to use the [GetElements](https://getopentest.org/reference/selenium-keywords.html#getelements) action.

```
- description: Find all li elements
  action: org.getopentest.selenium.GetElements
  args:
    locator: ... # This locator must match all li elements

- script: |
    var listItems = $output.elements;
    var itemsTextArray = listItems.map(function(li) {
          return li.getText();
        })
    // Next, check itemsTextArray for duplicate items
```